# SpriteKit: drawbacks of calling removeFromParent on node already removed parent?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

We use the following code to move sprites across the screen:

```
    let newPoint = CGPoint(x: target.position.x, y: target.position.y)
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(newPoint, duration: 2.0)
    let removeAction = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    dart.runAction(SKAction.sequence([
        moveAction,
        removeAction
    ]))
```

However, at some point before `removeAction` executes, another code block may execute (upon collision) and call `removeFromParent` on the same sprite. So far, the code executes fine. The second `removeFromParent` seems to be a no-op and doesn't generate an exception like we expected.

Are there drawbacks to calling `removeFromParent` from an already removed node, or can we leave the code as is?

Comment: If the `dart` might be already removed before the code you provided, shouldn't you check if it still there or not (in order to not create objects for nothing) ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. During the moveAction, a collision may occur which will result in removeFromParent() getting called. So the object always gets created; the question is: are there unforeseen consequences if removeFromParent() gets called twice.

Comment: You may consider to use hidden property for your darts instead of constantly recreating them. Just an idea. Have you tested what happens when you call twice removeFromParent ? Does your application crash?

Comment: No, @Whirlwind. As we stated in the question, the code executes fine, hence the question. Since we're new to Swift we want to make sure there are no gotchas down the line.